# Tile view not show product status

Tags: magento2, category, grid

I want to modify the tile view on the category page. Inside the category page, products in this category in Gird view, we can see the product status.

However, in Tile view, the status is not showing. Any way I can modify this?

I am appreciated for anyone can help

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using Adobe commerce version?

Comment: yes I am using 2.4.3-p1 cloud version